# Editing a local Pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm creating my first pod and I've been successfully able to define the spec and release a first version from an empty repository (only LICENSE here).

If I do

```
$ nano Podfile
$ cat Podfile
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MyPod', '~> 0.0.1'

$ pod install
```

I get my pod and its dependencies.

Now if I need to actually implement my pod, should I

- Initialize a project into my pod & install the required dependencies ?

  - In which case should I `gitignore` all and/or exclude files from the spec ?
- Create a separate project using my pod ?

  - In which case would I have to push from the pod / pull from the project for each modification ?

Maybe there are other solutions, what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a pod via `:path` it will be added as a development pod, which won't get changed/updated after initial `pod install`, not even during `pod update`. You can safely edit the files in its folder, and commit as you please.

The way I develop on a pod is to have a separate project which has this in the podfile:

```
  pod 'MyNewPod', :path => '~/Code/MyNewPod'
```

Obviously the `MyNewPod` folder has to contain your podspec so that the installation can be performed properly.

Comment: I've been successfully able to use `path` with `s.source = { :path => "." }` in the local podspec